# Is "négo" an accepted abbreviation for "négociation"?

Tags: québec, abréviations

Is "négo" an accepted abbreviation for "négociation" in Canada (Quebec).

Comment: In which context? I would certainly avoid it in any kind of somewhat formal professional environment.

Comment: I'm questioning the validity of the expression "profs en négo".

Comment: Once again, in which context. When discussing with fellow students?

Comment: No. It's an official slogan.

Comment: An official slogan for what? For whom?

Comment: Teacher's syndicate.

Comment: Pour un slogan ça se dit très bien. Tout le monde va comprendre le sens.

Comment: Probably just my anglo ear, but it could also sound close to "profs, on y go" or "profs, on est go", both of which would make good secondary meanings of the slogan (especially in case the collective bargaining breaks down).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Négo is indeed a commonly used term to shorten "négociation". It is not an abbreviation in itself; it is a short form.

It is also commonly used in the plural form, "négos".

In the case of the expression/slogan you are referring to, I suggest that you keep in mind that a slogan is used for its "punch" power and the fact that it could be used to be repeated in the streets for a protest.  Linguistically, it's not an excellent form, IMHO, but it conveys the message very quickly.